# Javascript or PHP create new date but only count business hours

Tags: javascript, php, date

I want to create a script to calculate if a new date based on today's date + X number of hours will be past a certain date or sooner. However, I want to consider only business hours (8am to 18pm) and week days (not Saturday or sunday).

Ex: Today's date - 11/12/2015 + 30 hours will result in which date if my day has only 10 hours and I don't count the Saturday or Sunday?

I have a script to do that, but is very unreliable. Does anyone have a simple solution? I couldn't find anything on the web.

```
function Diferenca($data1, $data2, $tipo){
if($data2==""){
    $data2 = date("d/m/Y H:i");
}
if($tipo==""){
    $tipo = "h";
}
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    ${"dia".$i} = substr(${"data".$i},0,2);
    ${"mes".$i} = substr(${"data".$i},3,2);
    ${"ano".$i} = substr(${"data".$i},6,4);
    ${"horas".$i} = substr(${"data".$i},11,2);
    ${"minutos".$i} = substr(${"data".$i},14,2);
}
$segundos = mktime($horas2,$minutos2,0,$mes2,$dia2,$ano2) - mktime($horas1,$minutos1,0,$mes1,$dia1,$ano1);
switch($tipo){
    case "m": $difere = $segundos/60;    break;
    case "H": $difere = $segundos/3600;    break;
    case "h": $difere = round($segundos/3600);    break;
    case "D": $difere = $segundos/86400;    break;
    case "d": $difere = round($segundos/86400);    break;
    case "s": $difere = $segundos;    break;
}
return $difere; }

function dec_Data($data){
$dia = substr($data, 8, 2);
$mes = substr($data, 5, 2);
$ano = substr($data, 0, 4);
$hr = substr($data, 11, 2);
$m = substr($data, 14, 2);
$data_retorno = $dia.'/'.$mes.'/'.$ano." ".$hr.":".$m;
return $data_retorno; }

if($data_cadastro_enc != '0000-00-00' and $data_cadastro_enc != '' and $sla_atend > 0 and $_POST["hora_abertura"] > 0 and $_POST["ativ_realizada"] != 'Projeto'){

    $data_cadastro_atend = $data_cadastro_enc." ".$_POST["hora_abertura"];  
    $ano_data_cadastro_atend = substr($data_cadastro_atend, 0, 4);
    $mes_data_cadastro_atend = substr($data_cadastro_atend, 5, 2);
    $dia_data_cadastro_atend = substr($data_cadastro_atend, 8, 2);
    $hr_data_cadastro_atend = substr($data_cadastro_atend, 11, 2);
    $mn_data_cadastro_atend = substr($data_cadastro_atend, 14, 2);

    $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_data_cadastro_atend + $sla_atend, $mn_data_cadastro_atend, 0, $mes_data_cadastro_atend, $dia_data_cadastro_atend, $ano_data_cadastro_atend);

    $diaSemana = getDate($timestamp_atend);
    $diaValor = $diaSemana[weekday];

    $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);

    $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
    $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
    $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
    $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
    $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

    switch ($diaValor){     
        case "Saturday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 2, $ano_nova_data_atend);
        break;

        case "Sunday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 1, $ano_nova_data_atend);
        break;

        default: $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);
    }

    $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    $val_hora_atend = $data_cadastro_enc." 18:00";

    while($nova_data_atend > $val_hora_atend){

        $data_dif = dec_Data($nova_data_atend);
        $data_dif_com = dec_Data($val_hora_atend);      

        $agora = Diferenca($data_dif_com, $data_dif, "m");

        $soma = $agora + 840;

        $ano_data_cadastro_atend_com = substr($val_hora_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_data_cadastro_atend_com = substr($val_hora_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_data_cadastro_atend_com = substr($val_hora_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_data_cadastro_atend_com = substr($val_hora_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_data_cadastro_atend_com = substr($val_hora_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_data_cadastro_atend_com, $mn_data_cadastro_atend_com + $soma, 0, $mes_data_cadastro_atend_com, $dia_data_cadastro_atend_com, $ano_data_cadastro_atend_com);

        $diaSemana = getDate($timestamp_atend);
        $diaValor = $diaSemana[weekday];

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);

        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        switch($diaValor){      
            case "Saturday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 2, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            case "Sunday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 1, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            default: $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);
        }

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
        $val_hora_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 10)." 18:00";

    }

    $hr_nova_data = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);

    if($hr_nova_data == 0){
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 14, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    } else if($hr_nova_data == 1) {
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 15, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    } else if($hr_nova_data == 2) {
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 16, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    } else if($hr_nova_data == 3) {
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 17, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    } else if($hr_nova_data == 4) {
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 32, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $diaSemana = getDate($timestamp_atend);
        $diaValor = $diaSemana[weekday];

        switch($diaValor){      
            case "Saturday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 32, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 2, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            case "Sunday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 32, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 1, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            default: $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 32, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);
        }

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    } else if($hr_nova_data == 5) {
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 33, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $diaSemana = getDate($timestamp_atend);
        $diaValor = $diaSemana[weekday];

        switch($diaValor){      
            case "Saturday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 33, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 2, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            case "Sunday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 33, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 1, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            default: $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 33, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);
        }

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    } else if($hr_nova_data == 6) {
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 34, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $diaSemana = getDate($timestamp_atend);
        $diaValor = $diaSemana[weekday];

        switch($diaValor){      
            case "Saturday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 34, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 2, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            case "Sunday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 34, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 1, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            default: $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 34, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);
        }

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    } else if($hr_nova_data == 7) {
        $ano_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 0, 4);
        $mes_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 5, 2);
        $dia_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 8, 2);
        $hr_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 11, 2);
        $mn_nova_data_atend = substr($nova_data_atend, 14, 2);

        $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 35, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);

        $diaSemana = getDate($timestamp_atend);
        $diaValor = $diaSemana[weekday];

        switch($diaValor){      
            case "Saturday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 35, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 2, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            case "Sunday": $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 35, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend + 1, $ano_nova_data_atend);
            break;

            default: $timestamp_atend = mktime($hr_nova_data_atend + 35, $mn_nova_data_atend, 0, $mes_nova_data_atend, $dia_nova_data_atend, $ano_nova_data_atend);
        }

        $nova_data_atend = date("Y-m-d H:i", $timestamp_atend);
    }

    $sla_atend_data = $nova_data_atend;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the script you have, and what it does that's unreliable.

Comment: share the code which you have tried.

Comment: It's a mess, but I'm posting it.

Comment: You might want to look at using a PHP library such as Carbon (http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) for some tested/reliable functions.  For example:  $myDate->isWeekend(); will return true/false if $myDate is/isnt in the weekend or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the following is something like what you need (free code is free code…). There are lots of quirks with dates, so the following tries a very simple algorithm to add hours in chunks, skip over weekends, and deal with any overruns. There are a few business rules:

1. If the start is after the finish of one business day and before the start time of the next, the start is moved to the start of the next business day. So if the start is 18:00 Sunday, it's moved to 08:00 Monday.
2. If the date provided isn't even hours, the minutes and seconds are preserved
3. The returned date may have a time of 18:00, e.g. if the start is 08:00 on a work day and 10 hours is added the returned date will be 18:00 on the same day.
4. If the start is 09:00 and 10 hours are added, the returned date will be 09:00 the next day

It uses a loop to add the days and hours. It could use logic like Paul S to work out how many days and go that way (I'd rather use *setDate* than *setHours*, but I guess that's just me) but this is simpler for my brain. Now that the algorithm is correct, it's easy to simplify the code (and maybe do the non-looping hours thing).

Hopefully the comments in the code are sufficient. Start hour, end hour and weekend days are configurable.

```js
/*  Add work hours to date, but only from 08:00 up to 18:00
**  and skip weekends (Saturday, Sunday)
**  Work in whole hours, bus
**
**  @param   {Date} date  - Date to add hours to
**  @param {number} hours - Integer number of hours to add
**  @returns {Date}       - new Date with work hours added.
*/
function addWorkHours(date, hours) {
  // Setable parameters
  var startHour = 8;
  var endHour = 18;
  // Weekend days to skip, one day for Sunday (0), two for Saturday (6)
  var weekendDays = {'6':2, '0':1};  // Western: Saturday, Sunday 
//  var weekendDays = {'4':2, '5':1};  // Arabic: Thursday, Friday
  
  // Calculated values
  var date = new Date(+date);  // Copy of provided date
  var hrsPerDay = endHour - startHour;
  var hrsToAdd, hrsLeftToday;
  // Make sure hours is a number
  hours = +hours;

  // If before start time, set to start
  if (date.getHours() < startHour) {
    date.setHours(startHour,0,0,0);
    
  // If after end time, set to start on next day
  } else if (date.getHours() > endHour) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    date.setHours(startHour,0,0,0);
  }
  
  // If on a weekend, skip to start hour on next working day
  if (date.getDay() in weekendDays) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + weekendDays[date.getDay()]);
    date.setHours(startHour, 0,0,0);
  }
  
  // Add hours to date during business hours until exhaused
  while (hours) {
  
    // Get number of work hours left today
    hrsLeftToday = endHour - date.getHours();
    
    // If hrsLeftToday is 0 and there are hours to add, go to start tomorrow
    if (!hrsLeftToday && hours) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
      date.setHours(startHour);
    }
    
    // Get hours to end time or remaining hours, whichever is less
    hrsToAdd = hrsLeftToday > hours? hours : hrsLeftToday;
    
    // Adjust hours
    hours -= hrsToAdd;
    
    // Add the hours, but don't go past end time
    // If hours to add is equal the hours in a day, and there are
    // more hours to add, just add one day
    if (hrsToAdd == hrsPerDay && hours) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    } else {
    
      // Otherwise, set the hours
      date.setHours(date.getHours() + hrsToAdd);
    }
    
    // If hours are zero, tidy any overlap past end hour if there is any
    if (!hours) {
    
      // If gone past end time in hours, run into next day
      if (date.getHours() > endHour) {
      
        // Get overrun, add a day and add back overrun
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        date.setHours(startHour + date.getHours() - endHour);
      }

      // Do the same with minutes
      if (date.getHours() == endHour && (date.getMinutes() || date.getSeconds())) {
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        date.setHours(startHour);
      }
    }

    // If now on a weekend, skip to next working day
    if (date.getDay() in weekendDays) {
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + weekendDays[date.getDay()]);
    }
  }
  return date;
}
// Helper to parse ISO input date string as local
function parseDate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(b[0],b[1]-1,b[2],b[3]||0,b[4]||0);
}

var d = parseDate(document.getElementById('startdate').value);
var h = document.getElementById('hrs').value;
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Start: ' + d + '<br>End: ' + addWorkHours(d, h);
```

```html
Date (yyyy-mm-dd [hh:mm:ss])<input type="text" id="startdate" value="2015-12-07"><br>
Hours to add (integer)<input type="text" id="hrs" value="100"><br>
<button onclick="
 var d = parseDate(document.getElementById('startdate').value);
 var h = document.getElementById('hrs').value;
 document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Start: ' + d + '<br>End: ' + addWorkHours(d, h); 
">Add hours</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: That is a very great code @RobG, however it not prevents the final date to end in after businnes hours. But I think I can adapt it. Thanks!

Comment: The returned date is always during business hours as defined by *startHour* and *endHour* and on a business day as the reciprocal of *weekendDays*, e.g. adding 11 hours to 2015-12-06 (a Sunday) returns 09:00 the following Tuesday (since the start is on a weekend, it's moved to 08:00 Monday, there are 10 working hours in a day and work starts at 08:00 so the end is 09:00 Tuesday).

Comment: Not really. Using your snippet, I entred the date 2015-12-07 15:33:00 and added 30 hours. The result was End: Thu Dec 10 2015 01:33:00 GMT-0200

Comment: Ok, fixed that, the more testing the better. :-) There are so  many business rules around this that coding them all becomes a real test. Likely the above only suits a small number of cases. I had a look at one that works out weeks, days and hours, then adds them without a loop but ends up even more code unless you fix the weekend to Sat and Sun, which doesn't suit in many cases. At least that part is simplified with a looping algorithm.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I've tried like 3 times to develop a good code for this calculation, but it always laked something. But your seems pretty great! Thanks again for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
function foo(start_time, plus_hours) {
    var time = new Date(+start_time),
        day;
    // rewind to the start of the hour
    time.setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
    // then
    if (time.getHours() < 8) { // if before work day
        time.setHours(8); // fast forward to start of work hours
    }
    if (time.getHours() >= 18) { // if after work day
        time.setDate(time.getDate() + 1);  // fast forward to tomorrow
        time.setHours(8); // start of work hours
    }
    if ([0, 6].indexOf(time.getDay()) !== -1) { // if it is weekend
        day = (time.getDay() && 2) || 1; // (no setDay method)
        time.setDate(time.getDate() + day); // fast foward to monday
        time.setHours(8); // start of work hours
    }
    // now convert plus_hours into day-length equivalents (i.e. add 14 hours for each 10 hours)
    plus_hours = plus_hours + (plus_hours - Math.floor(plus_hours % (18 - 8))) * (24 - (18 - 8)) / (18 - 8);
    // now work out how many hours we have until saturday
    day = time.getDay();
    day = (6 - day) * 24;
    day = day - time.getHours();
    // then
    if (plus_hours > day) { // if we are going to cross into future weeks
        // add 48 hours for each week (i.e. each 5 days)
        plus_hours = plus_hours - day;
        plus_hours = (plus_hours - Math.floor(plus_hours % (5 * 24))) * (2 * 24) / 5;
        plus_hours = plus_hours + day + 2 * 24;
    }
    return new Date(+time + plus_hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
}
```

It may have some trouble crossing timezones etc, probably needs ironing out but I've commented it so you get the concepts.

Comment: Good. We don't need loops to deal with weekends. Holidays, of course, are a different story. For clarity, I would suggest `day = time.getDay() == 0 ? 1 : 2`,  instead of `day = (time.getDay() && 2) || 1`. Or, for that matter or  `day = time.getDay() == 6 ? 2 : 1`.  Use of && and || obscures the intent of what you are doing.

Comment: Nice try, but it it's a little broken. 2015-12-07 plus 65 hours (6.5 working days) returns 2015-12-14 00:00 instead of 2015-12-15 13:00. Adding 100 hours (10 days) to the same date returns 2016-01-31 00:00 instead of 2015-12-18 18:00.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that accepts two `Date`s (the built-in JavaScript class) and a number of hours and returns `true` if the dates meet your criteria.

It will involves wrangling the `Date()` class a bit but it can be done.

```
var currentDate = new Date(); // new Date object with current date/time
currentDate; // "Fri Dec 11 2015 09:45:39 GMT-0800 (PST)"
currentDate.getHours(); // returns hours past midnight, in this case '9'
currentDate.getMinutes(); // returns minutes past last whole hour, in this case 45
currentDate.getDay(); // returns a number 1-7 representing Monday through Sunday

// creating a future date
var futureDate = new Date(2015, 12, 14, 9, 30); // 12/14/2015 at 9:30 AM
// the format is (year, month, date, hour, minute)
```

`getDay()` is your bread and butter because it will tell you if you're on a weekend or not (but not if it's a holiday, you'll need external data for that).

What I would do is start with the number of hours you're trying co calculate for, and iterate through each day between `currentDate` and `futureDate`, subtracting hours as you go. If you reach `0` hours before you get to `futureDate` then you know it's out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function getDateCompleted($date, $hours, $hoursPerDay) {
  if ($hoursPerDay == 0) {
    // Will never reach and prevent division by zero
    return null;
  }

  $daysToComplete = ceil((float)$hours / $hoursPerDay);
  $days = 0;
  $time =strtotime($date);
  while ($days < $daysToComplete) {
    // Check for weekend
     if (!(date('N', $date) >= 6)) {
        $current = $time;
        $days++;
    }
    $time = strtotime("+1 day", $time);
  }
  return date("Y-m-d", $current);
}

echo getDateCompleted("11/12/2015", 30, 10);
```

Prints 2015-11-16

Comment: Answers should explain why they answer the OPs question. There should be sufficient explanation or comments so that there's no need to read the code to understand what it's doing.